# Format meta_value

Tags: post-meta

I have a request to get postmeta records with a specific meta_value.

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( " SELECT * FROM  $wpdb->postmeta WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'wpcomplete' " );
foreach ( $result as $page ) {
 echo maybe_unserialize($page->meta_value).'<br/>';
}
```

result :

{"buttons":{"3":"1951965-debutant","4":"1951965-intermediaire","5":"1951965-expert"},"course":"examen"}

I just need to clean the result like that

**buttons :**

1951965-debutant

1951965-intermediaire

1951965-expert

**course :**

examen

Comment: That appears to be some somewhat strangely encoded JSON. You'd want to run the string through PHP's [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to turn it into an associative array or an object, after which you can compose your output by accessing the appropriate keys/fields. Aside: questions regarding generic PHP are [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here - if you need additional help with the code, Stack Overflow would be a better stack for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the meta value is *double* serialized.
Try this, it also cleans up your query, untested:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_column ( " SELECT meta_value FROM  $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'wpcomplete' " );

foreach ( $results as $result ) {

    $item = maybe_unserialize( $result ); 
    if ( is_serialized( $item ) {
       $item = maybe_unserialize( $item ); 
    }
    
    foreach( $item as $obj ) {
    
       foreach( $obj->buttons as $key => $value ) {
           echo $value . '<br>';
       }
       
       foreach( $obj->course as $key => $value ) {
           echo $value . '<br>';
       }
       
    }
    
}
```

If you know that the meta_key is exactly `'wpcomplete'`, then do not use `LIKE` - it is slow.  Instead, do this: `WHERE meta_key = 'wpcomplete'`